# alter table drop column fail in SSDT because of dependancy of non cluster index

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I have created an SSDT project for SQL Server 2012 database. since i have database already present in the SQL Server Database engine so i use the import feature to import all the objects into SSDT. everything works fine but i am now facing 2 problems

1) since one of the table is using the HIERARCHYID column (col1) as a datatype and there is one computed column based on the HIERARCHYID column. The definition of computed column is something like case Col1= hierarchy.GETRoot() THE NULL ELSE someexpression END. after importing the table script in SSDT, Error of unresolve reference start coming up.
If i change the defination to something like case hierarchy.GETRoot() = Col1 THE NULL ELSE someexpression END (note now col1 is now at the end) it works fine.

2) if i keep the above solution (i.e keeping col1 after =) then at the time of publishing the project,SSDT has to drop the column at the production server and then recreate it.  since there is a index depend on this column the deployment get failed everytime saying the error like ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN fail because other object access it. i have no control how SSDT design / publish the script. and if i have to keep any eye to drop every dependent object before publishing the database project then i think there is no use of it

Please suggest how i can resolve this

Thanks
Atul

Comment: I am running into this exact issue.. I have a computed column that is persisted with an index on it. The index is being ignored when dacpac deployment attempts to drop and recreate the index, and the deployment subsequently fails. I anticipate having to drop and recreate the index pre and post deployment script for now, however a valid solution would be preferred to a workaround. Any luck on this issue?

Comment: Confirmed it is an issue with the SSDT version we are using; see my answer below.

Comment: My answer ended up being a non answer. I edited it to say as much and have posted the bug on user voice as it still exists in the current verison of SSDT. As I mentioned in my answer, the workaround for now is pre and post deployment scripts for each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the reference resolution problem you described. I would suggest submitting that issue to Microsoft via Connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx

I was not able to reproduce the publish failure. Which version of SSDT does the Visual Studio Help > About dialog show is installed? The most recent version ends with 40403.0. If you're not using the most recent version, I would suggest installing it to see if that fixes the publish failure. You can use Tools > Extensions and Updates to download SSDT updates.

If you do have the most recent version, could you provide an example schema that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for this. this problem only exists if we are using any CLR datatype. i did try to do the same with int datatype column and it is working fine. The version of SSDT i am using is 11.1.40403.0

Comment: Could you provide an example schema? E.g. to reproduce the reference resolution, I have initial state script:

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] (
        [HID]    [sys].[hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
        [IsRoot] AS (case when [HID]=[hierarchyid]::GetRoot() then 1 else 0 end));

And revised state script:

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] (
        [HID]    [sys].[hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
        [IsRoot] AS (case when [hierarchyid]::GetRoot()=[HID] then 1 else 0 end));

Answer (score 0):

Compare your project to a production dacpac and have it generate scripts to make the changes. Then if need be, you can edit the scripts before they get applied to production. This is how my dev teams do it.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I was running into the same issue for a number of days now. After finding your post to confirm the issue was in SSDT, I realized that it may be fixed in a later version than the one we are currently using: 12.0.50730.0 (VS 2013, the version this project uses).</s>

I also have version 14.0.3917.1 installed from VS 2017. I just attempted with that, no issues. **So the solution is to upgrade your SSDT version**.

Please ignore that solution, it appears my success last night was anomalous. While attempting to repeat it today after restoring a database with the issue, the deployment failed to account for at least one index again.

EDIT: 
I have posted about this on User Voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33850309-computed-column-indexes-are-ignored-with-dacpac-de

Also, to maintain that this is at least a workable answer of sorts, the workaround I am implementing involves dropping and recreating the missed indexes myself using pre and post deployment scripts.

Not an ideal solution if the dacpac was meant to update various versions of the database that could have different levels of drift from the model, however it works for us as we have a tight control over all instances and can expect about the same delta generated each release for each db instance.